# Disable select in which option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it just put the select disabled one which I choose an option and do not disable all the select ones.

Example: in the first `select` selection `B Babel` Only that select gets disabled me

```js
$(function() {
  $('.asignar').on('click', function() {
    $(".widthSelect").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row center span10">
  <button type="button" class='asignar'>assign</button>
  <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>SELECT</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Escort</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Ranger</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Tacoma</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Mustang</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mercury</td>
        <td>Sable</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Corolla</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using this class 'widthSelect' in all that is why all the dropdowns are getting disable. You need to be more specific.

Comment: This is not clear at all? What do you want to disable?

Comment: You code has bigger problems. While the solutions below show examples using index and comparing text, I'm assuming you want to disable all elements with the class `widthSelect` you need to have code that adds/removes that class when values are selected then to ensure the class only exists on select elements which have a value selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) totarget `<select>` with [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property, and then disable them.

```
$(".widthSelect").filter(function() {
  return this.selectedIndex > 0;
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

And to manipulate properties i.e. `disabled` use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of `.attr()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.asignar').on('click', function() {
    $(".widthSelect").filter(function() {
      return this.selectedIndex > 0;
    }).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row center span10">
  <button type="button" class='asignar'>assign</button>
  <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>SELECT</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Escort</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Ranger</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Tacoma</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ford</td>
        <td>Mustang</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mercury</td>
        <td>Sable</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toyota</td>
        <td>Corolla</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
          <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.asignar').on('click', function(){
   $(".widthSelect").each( function(){
         if( $(this).find(":selected").text() != "select..." ){
          $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
         }
   });
   
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row center span10">
    <button type="button" class='asignar'>assign</button>
            <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
              <tr>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>SELECT</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Ford</td>
                  <td>Escort</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                   <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Ford</td>
                  <td>Ranger</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Toyota</td>
                  <td>Tacoma</td>
                  <td>Red</td>
                  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Ford</td>
                  <td>Mustang</td>
                  <td>Silver</td>
                  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Mercury</td>
                  <td>Sable</td>
                  <td>Silver</td>
                  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Toyota</td>
                  <td>Corolla</td>
                  <td>Blue</td>
                  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
                <select class="widthSelect">
                    <option id="ISIN1">select...</option>
                    <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                    <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                    <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this script will get desired result

```
 $(function(){
      $('.asignar').on('click', function(){
       $("#example-table select").each(function(){
       if($(this).val()!='select...')
       $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
       })
    });
    });
```